# How to check if a std::unique_ptr is null, if it is in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14, smart-pointers, stdvector

I have a `vector<unique_ptr<BaseClass>>`, and I am adding new items to it by calling `vec.push_back(std::make_unique<DerivedClass>())`.

How can I check for `nullptr` using `operator bool()`?

I tried to use `vec.back()` directly, like so:

```cpp
if((!vec.empty() && vec.back())
{
  // yay!
}
else
{
  //nay!
}
```

but it always returns with false, regardless of the contents of the pointer.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and which we might try and debug ourselves? Talking about debugging, you *have* tried to debug it yourself?

Comment: `std::make_unique()` will never return a `std::unique_ptr` that holds a `nullptr`. But `if (vec.back())` will invoke the `unique_ptr::operator bool` just fine, assuming `vec` is not empty (otherwise calling `back()` is *undefined behavior*). So whatever problem you are having is in code you have not shown.

Comment: Thank you! I would have accepted you comment as an answer though. Most likely the code I found to be faulty was not  related to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/), if the vector is empty, it's UB. If it's not your case, as you can read from [here instead](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/operator%20bool/), `unique_ptr` has a `operator bool()` which checks *whether an object is currently managed by the `unique_ptr`*

So, with:

```
vector.empty();
```

You can check if the vector has elements, and with:

```
vector<unique_ptr<something>> vec;
vec.push_back(make_unique<something>());
if(vec.front()){ // example
    // do something
}
```

you check whether the first `unique_ptr` is pointing to an object or not.

PS: if you always use `vec.push_back(std::make_unique<DerivedClass>())`, you will never have a `unique_ptr` that holds a `nullptr`

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, I also extended the question with the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The *@Berto99*'s answer has mentioned the problem(i.e. [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)) of calling the [`std::vector::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) for a empty `std::vector`.

In addition, like *@RemyLebeau* mentioned, if you use the `std::make_unique`, it will always return [the `std::unique_ptr` of an instance of type `T`(i.e. `BaseClass`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique#Return_value).

I would like to add something to your [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62993136/2). If you want to check anything regarding the last insertion, you could use [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), which returns (since C++17) the references to the inserted element.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> vec;
auto& lastEntry = vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<BaseClass>());

if (lastEntry) // pointer check
{
    // do something with the last entry!
}
```

As a plus over `std::vector::push_back`, your `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>` will be constructed in-place.